# Assign a public static function's return value to a private variable

Tags: php, methods, static, private, assign

There are two classes:

```
class Db {
    public static function getConnection () {
        /*Initialize parameters*/
        $db = new PDO (...);
        return $db;
    }
}
```

Class Db initializes and returns a PDO object.

Then I want to do following in another class:

```
class User {
    private $db = Db::getConnection();
    ....
}
```

Why am I getting an error here:

```
private $db = Db::getConnection();
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @Dacaspex unexpected ( after identifier 'getConnection'

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/18092308#18092308 usually these errors indicates an unclosed `(` or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the error, it's hard to say, but I'd guess is because you can't do that there, try this.

```
class User {
    private $db = null;

    function __construct(){
        $this->db = Db::getConnection();
    }

    public function getFriends(){
        return $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM friends');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `private $db;` ?

Comment: I guess personal preference, I always give a value if I can, although it's not needed.

Comment: @TomHart If I use this option, $db will be initialized only when I create an object with new operator. But I want to use this $db variable inside my methods in User class.

Comment: Will `User` just be static methods? Otherwise you'd have to instantiate the object anyway

Comment: @TomHart No. The `User` class will have methods like `login()`, `getFriends`, etc. Each of these methods makes a SQL query to database, so I would have to have `Db::getConnection()` in each method. So I want a $db property which can be accessed from each method.

Comment: This will be. In each method, just use `$this->db->yourMethod(...);`. I've added an example method

Comment: Yeah, this works, thanks @TomHart. Why didn't `private $db = Db::getConnection();` work though?

Comment: I don't think you can do any functions in a class, outside of a method. So you can't do something like `private $time = time();` it has to be in a method.